# Thread stopped C:\... Fault: integer divide by 0x401203 error en borland 5.02

Tags: c, c++98

Uso Borland 5.02 por un trabajo de la universidad... y por alguna razón el programa no es capaz de asignar valores de variables en otras variables en funciones matemáticas simples.

Éste es mi código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
main()
{
  int m, s, cs, mt,h,km;
  float t1,t2,s2, v;
  printf("Introduzca minutos: "); scanf("%i",&m);
  printf("Introduzca segundos: "); scanf("%i",&s);
  printf("Introduzca centecimas de segundos: "); scanf("%i",&cs);
  printf("Introduzca metros: "); scanf("%i",&mt);

  if(m<60 && s<60 && cs<100 || 0>m && 0>s && 0>cs && 0>mt)
  {
    t1=m*60;
    t2=cs/100;
    s2=t1+t2+s;
    h=(s2/60)/60;
    km=mt/1000;
    v=h/km;
    printf("Su velocidad fue de: %8.2f kmh", (v));
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Error.");
  }
  getch();
}
```

Comment: uso borland 5.02 por un trabajo de la universidad... y por alguna razon el no es capaz de asignar valores de variables en otras variables en funciones matematicas simples.

Comment: ¿Con qué valores falla?¿En qué línea te da el error?¿Es en `v=h/km`?

Comment: si discupa es la primera ves usando esta pagina, olvide señalarlo, si de hecho ese es probablemente el problema que me esta causando estragos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en cómo defines las variables `mt` y `km`, y en estas dos líneas:

```
km=mt/1000;
v=h/km;
```

`mt` es un entero (`int`), al dividirlo por 1000 va a devolver un valor entero redondeado hacia abajo. Eso quiere decir que si el usuario escribe un valor menor de 1000 para `mt`, `km` será 0. Entonces la segunda línea será una una división por cero y por eso obtienes el error que indicas en la pregunta.

La solución: convierte tanto `mt` como `km` en floats y cambia la lectura de `mt` (de `%i` a `%f` al ser ahora un float), y el problema se resuelve:

> También deberías hacer que `h` sea un float o para valores pequeños siempre obtendrás 0

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
main()
{
  int m, s, cs;
  float t1,t2,s2, v, km, mt, h;
  printf("Introduzca minutos: "); scanf("%i",&m);
  printf("Introduzca segundos: "); scanf("%i",&s);
  printf("Introduzca centecimas de segundos: "); scanf("%i",&cs);
  printf("Introduzca metros: "); scanf("%f",&mt);

  if(m<60 && s<60 && cs<100 || 0>m && 0>s && 0>cs && 0>mt)
  {
    t1=m*60;
    t2=cs/100;
    s2=t1+t2+s;
    h=(s2/60)/60;
    km=mt/1000;
    v=h/km;
    printf("Su velocidad fue de: %8.2f kmh", (v));
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Error.");
  }
  getch();
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, en verdad no habia notado eso y pensado bien con que objetivo queria esos elementos.